# Typescript: Infer lookup type for function parameter within object

Tags: typescript, types

Defining a general purpose table. That takes data and a schema for how to display it. Here is a simplified example of how to call it.

```
<PagedTable
  data={[ username: 'rob', logins: 32 ]}
  schema={[
    {
      key: 'username',
      customRender: (targetData, row) => fnThatOnlyTakesStrings(targetData)
    } 
   ]}
 />
```

The component class has the following signature:

```
class PagedTable<T> extends Component<Props<T>, any>
```

and the props:

```
interface Props<T> {
  data: T[] | null | undefined
  schema: ColumnDef<T>[]
}

interface ColumnDef<T> {
  key?: keyof T
  customRender?: <U extends keyof T>(
    targetData: T[U],
    rowData: T
  ) => string | JSX.Element
}
```

So the concrete type for the class is inferred correctly.

For completeness, inside PagedTable the simplified rendering function for the cell is:

```
renderCell(datum: T, { customRender, key }: ColumnDef<T>) {
  if (customRender) {
    return customRender(datum[key!], datum, key!)
  } else {
    return datum[key]
  }
}
```

What I want is for `targetData` to get the correct type when using the customRender function. In this setup it's type is `number | string` which is incorrect.

Is there a way to infer the type just using the `key` property of a schema object (which is guaranteed to be a key of a data object)?

Answer (score 2):

I think your main problem is that you probably don't want `customRender` to be a generic function.  It shouldn't be that any `customRender` can take a `T[U]` for *any* `U`, but that each `customRender` expects a *particular* `U`.  After all, `(targetData, row) => fnThatOnlyTakesStrings(targetData)` seems to expect that `targetData` is a `string`, which only works for some *particular* key, right?

So I think you really want `ColumnDef` to be generic in both `T` and `U`, like this:

```
interface ColumnDef<T, U extends keyof T> {
  key?: U
  customRender?: (
    targetData: T[U],
    rowData: T
  ) => string | JSX.Element
}
```

This ends up needing to propagate out to other things that refer to `ColumnDef`:

```
interface Props<T, U extends keyof T> {
  data: T[] | null | undefined
  schema: ColumnDef<T, U>[]
}

class PagedTable<T, U extends keyof T> extends React.Component<Props<T, U>, any> {
  renderCell(datum: T, cd: ColumnDef<T, U>) {
    if (cd.customRender) {
      return cd.customRender(datum[cd.key! as any as U], datum)
    } else {
      return datum[cd.key!]
    }
  }
}
```

(I'm not sure if the changes I made to `renderCell` are necessary or if it behaves as desired, but I got errors having to do with number of arguments and I fixed it until it didn't complain.  You should alter it to suit your needs).

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Shall try out soon but for now, +1 for `as any as U`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, the tricky aspect is that `schema` can have multiple `ColumnDef`s of different types, and the key of *each* `ColumnDef` needs to correspond to its `customRender` function.  In order for TypeScript to infer and enforce a different type for each `ColumnDef`, you'll need to wrap each `ColumnDef` in a function call.  Then I found that I needed to explicitly specify `T` in order for the inference to work; hopefully that won't be a hassle because I assume in a real application you already have type definitions for `T`.  This code is working for me:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Props<T> {
  data: T[] | null | undefined
  schema: WrappedColumnDef<T>[]
}

interface ColumnDef<T, U extends keyof T> {
  key?: U
  customRender?: (
    targetData: T[U],
    rowData: T
  ) => string | JSX.Element
}

const WRAPPED_COLUMN_DEF_MARKER = Symbol();
interface WrappedColumnDef<T> extends ColumnDef<T, any> { 
  [WRAPPED_COLUMN_DEF_MARKER]: undefined;
}

declare function wrapColumnDef<T, U extends keyof T>(arg: ColumnDef<T, U>): WrappedColumnDef<T> { 
  return arg as WrappedColumnDef<T>;
}

declare class PagedTable<T> extends React.Component<Props<T>, any> {}

declare function fnThatOnlyTakesStrings(arg: string): string;

interface MyDatum { 
  username: string;
  logins: number;
}

let x = <PagedTable<MyDatum>
  data={[{ username: 'rob', logins: 32 }]}
  schema={[
    wrapColumnDef({
      key: 'username',
      customRender: (targetData, row) => fnThatOnlyTakesStrings(targetData)
    })
   ]}
 />;
```

Comment: Shall try out soon but for now, +1 for demonstrating how to specify the type on a JSX component.